# Search @covers to run phpUnit tests which cover a class or method

Tags: php, phpunit

I am writing a q&d auto-testing script, and I want to run all the tests which cover the class I am working on.

When I edit:

```
    class Foo {
        public function Bar(){...}
        public function Baz(){...}
    }
```

I want to run tests with:

```
    @covers Foo
    @covers Foo::Bar
    @covers Foo::Baz
```

Is there any way to run phpUnit to search for tests tagged with `@covers`?
If so, can I search for particular strings within the `@covers` tag?

Comment: Why not add the @group annotation to your tests as well?

Comment: I could mimic this with careful `@group` settings, but that's not what I want. I want to use `@covers` for code coverage *and* for auto-running tests when the `@covered` method is changed. If it turns out to be very difficult, I'll use `@groups` instead.